# Is there a way to use a "template reference variable" with Angular 4?

Tags: angular, pug

I am trying to figure how to use a template reference variable in a .pug template.

For example: `div(#var)` will throw an error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "#var" (" ...
```

The cause is that pug will render as  :

```
<div #var="#var"> ...
```

Angular will then fail.

Comment: Can you put the complete code and the framework architecture you are using? Angular has its own template engine and seems that it is a compile error due to incorrect syntax usage. Why not use Angular Templating itself?

Comment: A possible solution will be using normal html for this tag, but is there a way for those with 'CODE OCTs'? Thanks

Comment: The issue is # of #var is a reserved syntax for local dom definition of angular. Angular compiler will definitely have an issue. I have no issue with mixing two templating - the problems starts is when two syntax's mix up or when changes happen. Not recommended.

Comment: I know about the possible problems mixing, but the benneffits are greatter. For example: better readability, simple code, less typing, etc.

Comment: Frankly, I do not recommend you do it. In such a case, I would recommend you to use backbonejs + pug or backbonejs + rivetjs. Do think again about the framework usage again. Why bloat your application?

Answer (score 7):

From the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-):

> **Template reference variables ( #var )**
>
> A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element
>   within a template. It can also be a reference to an Angular component
>   or directive or a web component.

So, you just need `<div #var >` ,The #var declares a `var` variable on this `<div>` element.

> In most cases, Angular sets the reference variable's value to the
>   element on which it was declared.... **But a directive can change that 
>   behavior and set the value to something else, such as itself. The
>   NgForm directive does that**

If you assign something in the template ref variable, it should be a **directive** or a **component**, for example: `#var="ngForm"` which [ngForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) is a built-in directive.

So that's why you get an error: `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "#var"`

Because **#var** (you assigned with: `<div #var="#var">`) is not a component nor a directive,

Now for jade (pug), if you want a null attribute,you should set the compiler [to compile to HTML doctype](https://pugjs.org/language/doctype.html#doctype-option) because the default behaviour of pug is to set an attribute value which is the same name on the attribute:

**default behaviour:**

`div(#var)` compiled to: `<div #var="#var"></div>`

`div(hidden)` compiled to `<div hidden="hidden"></div>`

**with doctype html**:

`div(#var)` compiled to: `<div #var></div>`

`div(hidden)` compiled to `<div hidden></div>`

Or you can just put in beginning of the file:`doctype html` for each file you want this.

Comment: Thanks, I knew the reason but where looking for a way to bypass it without using only html.

Comment: @JesusSegnini what if you add `doctype html` for jade compiler?

Comment: why isn't the doctype behavior the default one?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case and was looking how to solve it.

I found this solution:

Example: `div('#refMyDiv'='')`

Resource:
https://medium.com/paramsingh-66174/pugjs-primer-for-your-next-angular-4-project-409ee6696fad